# Question regarding API JSON to dataframe, exploding an element into rows

Tags: json, pandas

I've looked the previously asked questions regarding this topic, and am still not able to figure out my error / issue.

I am wanting to convert an API JSON file into a dataframe, and flatten the elements from the 'startTimes' into individual rows.

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
data = response.json()

df = pd.json_normalize((data['data']))
print(df)

df_initial_startTimes = df['startTimes']
```

the initial df returns a flat dataframe:
availability  ... request.maxCarrierLeadTime_hr
0  [{'start': '2024-01-16T18:26:00.000Z', 'end': ...  ...                           168

df_initial_startTimes returns:
[1 rows x 46 columns]
0    [2024-01-16T19:00:00.000Z, 2024-01-16T20:00:00...

I am looking for way to separate each of these elements within the cell into individual rows (comma separated).  I have tried string split, but it returned a blank dataframe.  The dtype is O - Object

Comment: Update: I've been able to answer this question.  Probably not in the most concise manner - this is the approach I took.  I used print(json.dumps(data, indent = 4)) to understand the structure, which then allowed me to add these three lines of exact the elements I was wanting to scrap:                                                                                                                   
    wh = data['data'][0]['warehouse']['name']
    tz = data['data'][0]['warehouse']['timezone']
    st = data['data'][0]['startTimes']